# I made a pile of balls using particle system and physics and now i want to replicate and transform this pile as an object not a simulation

Tags: particles, physics, fluid-simulation, instances, conversion

I tried going to modifiers tab and click convert on the particle system modifier, but that tries to convert the whole simulation and crashes my pc , I only want to convert one frame of the simulation to object and transform it how i want , Anyone can help?

Comment: If your particles have meshes in the particle render settings, you can use the Make Instances Real Command. Which will make every single particle object a separate object for that one frame.